# JSONP - Can I Provide Data From PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to deal with cross-domain issues in javascript and am just beginning to learn about JSONP.  I tried the following hoping it would work, but either I made a boo-boo or I don't fully understand the concept:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
 $.getJSON( "https://somedomain.com/dash-beta/workers/ip.php?format=json&callback=?", function(data){ 
    alert (data.ip); 
     });

 </script>
```

The script on the other side is returning the data in this format:

```
({"ip":"0.0.0.0"})
```

But the alert never fires.  For that matter, if I put "alert('woo!');' in its place, it doesn't fire.   Where a I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On PHP side you should return passed `callback`:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '({"ip":"0.0.0.0"});';
```

Comment: Have you been told you rock recently?